# No command found to return database results from stored procedure using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying use stored procedure `usp_WebPortalUserSearchResults` which was created in SQL Server database with 6 parameters.

Below is how I've verified the Entity Framework Core version. When verified packages section in the Solution Explorer, found as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(5.0.9)`. Hence, I'm assuming that I'm using Entity Framework Core v5.

I tried a number of approaches to return data from stored procedure, but nothing is working to return data.

Below is the information about stored procedure, and its parameters. This stored procedure should return `User` details.

```
usp_UserSearchResults
    @AccountNum as integer,
    @UserId as uniqueidentifier,
    @UserName as nvarchar(100),
    @FirstName as nvarchar(100),
    @LastName as nvarchar(100),
    @Email as nvarchar(100)
```

Below are just some of the ways, how I've tried. Can someone suggest me what's the right approach to get the result back into C# using Entity Framework Core?

With this code, Visual Studio 2019 Editor is reporting that `ExecuteSqlCommand` could not be found:

```
var commandText = "usp_WebPortalUserSearchResults";
SqlParameter sqlPrmAccountNum = new SqlParameter("@AccountNum", model.AccountNum);
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, sqlPrmAccountNum);
```

Below is how I've tried as an alternative way, this was not even success. Can someone please let me know how to approach for the solution!

```
var webPortalUsers = new List<WebPortalUser>();

using (var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "dbo.usp_WebPortalUserSearchResults";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var sqlPrmAccountNum = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "AccountNum",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = model.AccountNum
        };

    command.Parameters.Add(sqlPrmAccountNum);

    var sqlPrmUserId = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "UserId",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = model.UserId
        };
    command.Parameters.Add(sqlPrmUserId);

    var sqlPrmUserName = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "UserName",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Size = 100,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = model.UserName
        };
    command.Parameters.Add(sqlPrmUserName);

    var sqlPrmFirstName = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "FirstName",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Size = 100,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = model.FirstName
        };

    command.Parameters.Add(sqlPrmFirstName);

    var sqlPrmLastName = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "LastName",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Size = 100,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = model.LastName
        };

    command.Parameters.Add(sqlPrmLastName);

    var sqlPrmEmail = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "Email",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Size = 100,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = 100
        };
    command.Parameters.Add(sqlPrmEmail);

    command.Parameters["AccountNum"].Value = model.AccountNum;
    command.Parameters["UserId"].Value = model.UserId;
    command.Parameters["UserName"].Value = model.UserName;
    command.Parameters["FirstName"].Value = model.FirstName;
    command.Parameters["LastName"].Value = model.LastName;
    command.Parameters["Email"].Value = model.Email;

    _context.Database.OpenConnection();

    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        webPortalUsers.Add(new WebPortalUser
            {
                AccountNum = Convert.ToInt32(result["AccountNum"]),
                //MYTODO: Need to fix this: UserId = Convert.(result["UserId"]),
                UserName = Convert.ToString(result["UserName"]),
                FirstName = Convert.ToString(result["FirstName"]),
                LastName = Convert.ToString(result["LastName"]),
                Email = Convert.ToString(result["Email"])
            });
    }
}

return webPortalUsers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks ok. It seems that the problem is in your `stored procedure`. I suggest you add `NOCOUNT ON` to the beginning of your `sp`

```
create procedure [dbo].usp_UserSearchResults
as
begin

NOCOUNT ON;

...

NOCOUNT OFF;

end
```

With `NOCOUNT ON` you can get `select` statement result in your `sp`.

`NOCOUNT ON` stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set.

Take a lool at [SET NOCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi @M. Mohabbati Thank you for your answer. In fact, for me, this problem came due to ASP.NET Core MVC Project upgradation from v2.1 to v3.1